# How to use Javascript variables in PHP and PHP variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

## Self Answer

I have a script that is supposed to use AJAX to retrieve a video from Youtube, but, it requires AJAX to grab a PHP file. This PHP file needs Javascript variable to work, however, I could not seem to find a way to do this on this website. I found a way do to it with Jquery on this [Qoura question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-call-a-Php-file-from-a-Javascript-file-and-also-how-do-I-get-some-value-from-Php-into-Javascript-file).

But if you don't want to go there for whatever reason(I made some adjustments to the PHP code because it was created very poorly), to make a Javascript variable a PHP variable, you would use this
(I'm not incredibly skilled with jQuery at all so I won't attempt to explain it, and also, keep in mind that these are just basic examples, this easily can be abstracted in multiple ways)

### Jquery:

```
var username=$('input').val();
$.ajax({
url:'link_to_php_file',
method:'get',
data:{name:username},
success:function(data)
{
alert("Success");
},
error:function(data)
{
alert("error");
}
});
```

and the PHP for this is

### PHP:

`<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>`

Making a PHP variable into a Javascript variable is much simpler, however, is not a replacement for the above.

### PHP

`<?php echo "<script>showname('" . $_GET['username'] . "')</script>"`

### JavaScript

```
<script>
    function showname(username) {
        alert(username);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: It's just `$_GET['name']`, as that's what you've named it.

Comment: There's a checkbox when posting that allows you to write a self answer and post it at the same time...

Comment: _I could not seem to find a way to do this on this website_ - copy-paste your question title into Google. I assure you this topic has been thoroughly covered **many** times.

Comment: @Chris I do not understand how this could in any sense be a duplicate of that question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't actually ask a question. If you are posting a "self answer" question as a public service you should still phrase it as a question, and then post the solution as an answer. Also, the first part seems to be saying "can't do it with Javascript but can with jQuery" - not sure if that's what you meant, but it is wrong: using jQuery *is* using Javascript; jQuery can't do anything that JS can't.

Answer (score 1):

How to use PHP variable inside JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var stack = <?php echo $overflow; ?>;
</script>
```

I mean it is pretty simple. This code must be near PHP code that have $overflow variable itself.

If you want JavaScript variable inside PHP code then single way is using AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://domain-name.com/ask.php",
        data: { name: "Stackoverflow" },
        success: function() { alert('Yes, I work'); },
        dataType: "json"
    });
</script>
```

More detail about JQuery & AJAX you will see in [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).
Now In you ask.php you have:

```
$nameForSomethink = $_POST['name'];
```

After, you can do anything that you need.

I hope you understand my idea.

Comment: I suppose you hadn't noticed this was a self-answer question but thanks for your answer

Comment: @Beaux: You should make it an actual self _answer_ next time, by posting question and answer separately. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url:'link.php',
method:'get',
dataType: "json",
data:{name:youtubevideo},
success:function(data)
{
$('.video').attr("src", data[0]);
},
error:function(data)
{
alert("error");
}
});


   <?php
     $return = array();
     database or other stuff $_GET['name']
       foreach ($rows as $row){
          array_push($return, $row['url']);
       }
     echo json_encode($return);
   ?>
```

not sure something like this?